# docker-compose using volume from exisiting container

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, volumes

New to docker and docker-compose, have written compose file that starts couple of services one of which relies on mongo database.  I downloaded mongo image a while back and loaded it with data in a container.  When I start my mongo instance up via docker-compose starts a new container based on empty image so don't get the data.

Been reading about volumes as a way of trying to get compose to use the data from the existing container and have tried several permutations now and just can't get it to find the data.

When I start the container with the data and do inspect I get :

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "3f78b88e3e06f31d5f65a45bb1cb964245551875218d065162625cc73e662b1e",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/3f78b88e3e06f31d5f65a45bb1cb964245551875218d065162625cc73e662b1e/_data",
            "Destination": "/data/configdb",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "d3f89470c9f8c53b55c30338f691eb1586600343004c502feffe8f81091d7d5c",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/d3f89470c9f8c53b55c30338f691eb1586600343004c502feffe8f81091d7d5c/_data",
            "Destination": "/data/db",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

So am I right in saying I need to somehow get new container to use these mount points using volume tag ?

Have tried:

```
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: /var/lib/docker/volumes/3f78b88e3e06f31d5f65a45bb1cb964245551875218d065162625cc73e662b1e/_data
    target: /data/configdb
    volume:
      nocopy: true

  - type: volume
    source: /var/lib/docker/volumes/d3f89470c9f8c53b55c30338f691eb1586600343004c502feffe8f81091d7d5c/_data
    target: /data/db
    volume:
      nocopy: true
```

and :

```
volumes:
  - /data/configdb:/var/lib/docker/volumes/3f78b88e3e06f31d5f65a45bb1cb964245551875218d065162625cc73e662b1e/_data
  - /data/db:/var/lib/docker/volumes/d3f89470c9f8c53b55c30338f691eb1586600343004c502feffe8f81091d7d5c/_data
```

But to be honest grasping at straws, any help in an example of what I should be doing to use the exisiting data would be much appreciated.

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Compose file format v3.0+, try change the `type` option to `bind` in your volumes definition. The difference is that for `volume` type, when provided, the `source` refers to the name of named volume. For `bind`,  the `source` refers to the path to the file or directory on the Docker daemon host.

You can read more about the different types of mount in the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/#choose-the-right-type-of-mount).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Create a name volume with docker `volume create data_storage`
2. Start mongo with the volume `docker run -d -v data_storage:/data/db --name
       mongoding mongo`
3. Create a data base and add some documents to a collection
4. Kill the container and start a new one to see it working.

   docker container inspect 708bf6fe0a5b

   ```
       "Mounts": [
       {
           "Type": "volume",
           "Name": "data_storage",
           "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/data_storage/_data",
           "Destination": "/data/db",
           "Driver": "local",
           "Mode": "z",
           "RW": true,
           "Propagation": ""
       },
   ```

[Read more here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)